# How to get items from collection by created_at date with using only Y-m-d part?

Tags: laravel

I have a collection with records that include the created_at row. Now i want to get specific rows by date without time. I mean :

```
$users->whereLoose('created_at', '2016-11-23')
```

of course this returns empty but the format I need to use is "Y-m-d" without the "H:i:s" part. How can use this format to get records from the collection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could also use the `filter` method and the `isSameDay()` method.

```
$date = \Carbon\Carbon::parse('2016-11-23');

$usersForDate = $users->filter(function ($user) use ($date) {

    return $user->created_at->isSameDay($date);

});
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
$date = Carbon::parse('2016-11-23'); //Replace for your date
$users->where('created_at', '>', $date->startOfDay())
      ->where('created_at', '<', $date->endOfDay());
```

Or you could try this:

```
$users->whereDate('created_at', '=', '2016-11-23');
```

Comment: when i use your suggestion i get a BadMethodCallException with message 'Method whereDate does not exist.'. I guess its because i use 5.2?

Comment: @Skeletor : You're correct... whereDate() was introduced in 5.3.

Comment: @Skeletor no [I can see it in 5.2](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/5.2/Query/Builder.php#L1063).

Comment: hmm yes you are right but ist for builder. I am looking something for a collection not a method for the query itself.

Comment: @Skeletor I see, then you can use first solution. )

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin I don't want to use it on the query because there are alot of dates at that would do a lot of queries. that is why i stuffed all in to a collection and do the work afterwards.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin yepp then i will try your first solution

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the map() function on the collection per the docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-map

```
$collection = collect(['taylor', 'abigail', null])->map(function ($name) {
    return strtoupper($name);
})
->reject(function ($name) {
    return empty($name);
});
```